# How can I reproduce method behavior offline and debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have C# code that runs on the remote machine, I would like to reproduce the method operation in debug mode,
for example:

```
public static class calc
{
    public static int addingSum = 0;
    public static int subSum = 0;
    public static List<int> aList = new List<int>();
    public static List<int> bList = new List<int>();
    public static void dummyMethod(int a, int b)
    {
        this.addingSum += a + b;
        this.subSum += a - b;
        this.aList.add(a);
        this.bList.add(b);
    }
}
```

I would like to record how this method is behaving in runtime on remote machine and reproduce it later in my local machine with debugger
I did it before by serialize the all objects/variable and mock it using unit test, my question is if there is any simpler way?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you asking? Did you encounter problems due to the static data, and the modifiable public lists? The static fields prevent serialization *and* ensure there's no way to avoid inconsistent behavior. Anyone can modify `aList` and `bList` without calling `dummyMethod`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why is `calc` static in the first place? It would be better to convert all fields to static *and* private, make `dummyMethod` a public instance method, and use either a separate read-only property or method to retrieve the results of any calculation. Once you do that you'll be able to serialize the state of `calc` using any serializer

Comment: the method is only an example, the target is to reproduce reproduce scenario that happened in remote machine by recording all objects somehow